# Rails error sending string instead of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

trying to solve this problem in my Rails app with a select field. My app has a Category model, which has_many Products. I'm trying to submit a form so that a category is added to each Product instance, but I'm getting an error that looks like this: "Category(#70274155683560) expected, got String(#70274305215280)" . Here's my form select:

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id ]}, :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

Here's category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products, :foreign_key => 'category_id'
end
```

And here's the code from Product.rb that matters:

```
belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => 'category_id'
validates :category, presence: true
```

Finally, the products_Controller code that matters:

```
def product_params 
 params.require(:product).permit(:name, :decimal_price, :description, :photo, :destroy_photo, :category)
end

def create
@product = Product.new(product_params)
@product.set_user!(current_user)
respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    flash.now[:notice] = "Your item is for sale!"
    format.html {render :action => "show"}
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Woops, looks like something went wrong."
    format.html{render :action => "create"}
  end
end
end
```

Any ideas?

Edit
Here's what the params hash looks like when I try and submit the form:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"tdJX1tU8M91N2IBzHFBGMc4/RhREs2RSnKQc4plGyjs=",
 "product"=>{"name"=>"dsfsd",
 "decimal_price"=>"3.5",
 "description"=>"fdsfsddfs",
 "category"=>"2"},
 "commit"=>"List!"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
```

By the way, do you actually have a `category_id` integer field in your Products model and table? If you don't have that, then it will throw the error you mention. You'll need to add it using a migration.

Comment: Try with the edit I made. Essentially you're getting the error because that you are telling it to expect a category object (in your strong params) but then giving it a category id as a string. If my latest edit doesn't work, we can jump into a chat session.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @daniula: Please explain why it does not provide an answer to the question.